# SPS 2013 Document Set view all Properties

Tags: document, document-set

From inside a document set, in the Welcome page, I select "View All Properties"
[image]

But the only property it shows is the Name field....

[image]

The "Edit Properties" shows all of the fields.....

[image]

Can anyone help?? Users are on my back big time......

Answer (score 1):

Well I called MS Support because it was causing a work stoppage. Here's the result....

It was caused by adding a web part to the DISPFORM.aspx. I added a list web part to the form (notes that were filtered by the Name field).

When you add a list web part to the form it adds a line to the aspx file:

TemplateName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">DocumentLibraryForm TemplateName
[image]

which in turn breaks it... lol (causing you to not see the columns associated with the content type, in this case "Document Set")

if you comment out that line (on the DISPFORM.aspx) it behaves as expected, I can now see all of the columns on the forms..... you can even leave the web part on the page.

My next step is to get my support ticket back. I believe that it was SPS (that added the line of code) that caused the issue, not something that I did.... thoughts?

-bill

I neglected to mention I am using SPS 2013 EE... this issue was also reproduced on SPS 2010 by MS Support.

This appears to happen ONLY when you add a list view web part to a Document Library Form..... I have list view web part on list forms and it does not cause a problem.